# PostgreSQL doesn't use grant for a view

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I have a view called `viw_insideworktime` and it makes a `SELECT` for the `worktime` table, however when trying to select the error below appears:

`SELECT * FROM viw_insideworktime;`

`ERROR:  permission denied for table worktime`

I already tried to apply grants to the user, but the error persists.
The grant applied was as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE viw_insideworktime TO jobwork;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE worktime TO jobwork;
```

However, if I try to access the table directly, the data is displayed.

**Solved:**

I solved the problem by deleting the view and applying the GRANT below:

```
GRANT SELECT ON viw_insideworktime TO jobwork;
GRANT SELECT ON worktime TO jobwork;
```

Was there any other solution without having to delete the view?

Answer (score 0):

If you defined the view without the `security_invoker` option, permissions on the underlying tables are checked for the view owner, so you would have to

```
GRANT SELECT ON worktime TO view_owner;
```

If the view was defined with `security_invoker`, you'd have to grant the privilege to the role that uses the view.